# VHDL FSM with a counter inside

Tags: vhdl, fsm

I am new here and here is my question:

I have a state machine with 3 states(s0,s1.s2) and input:(reset, clk, start) and output (done). My state machine works like this: on reset it comes to s0, and then if start = '1' goes to s2 and in this state I want it to stay there for 12 clock cycles (12 clock cycle delay) and then goes to s2 and done ='1' here and then back to s0.
My codes goes like this :

My code seems fine but my simulation result is not ok.

```
    LIBRARY ieee;
    USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

    ENTITY fsm_count IS
    port(clk : in std_logic;
        reset : in std_logic;
        start : in std_logic ;
        don : out std_logic );

    END ENTITY fsm_count;

--
    ARCHITECTURE arc OF fsm_count IS
     type statetype is (s0,s1,s2);
    signal pr_state,nx_state : statetype;
    signal s_counter : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0):=(others=>'0');  -- zero

    begin
    fsmcount: process(clk,reset,pr_state,start)
    begin
      if reset = '1'then pr_state <= s0;
      elsif (clk'event and clk='1') then

      case pr_state is 

        when s0 => 
        if start ='1' then nx_state <=s1;
        else nx_state <= s0;
        end if;

       when s1 =>
         s_counter <= s_counter + '1';
         if (s_counter = "1100") then 
           nx_state <= s2;
           s_counter <=(others =>'0'); -- initializing the counter back to zero
         else nx_state <=s1;

         end if;

       when s2 => 
         nx_state<= s0;


      end case;
    end if;
     end process fsmcount;

      don <= '1' when  (pr_state = s2) else '0';             
    END ARCHITECTURE arc;
```

Comment: You need to include a minimal version of your code that shows us how your design works

Comment: yes I was just eddinting my question .

Comment: Your counter is not in a synchronous process; it probably doesn't do what you want. Have you tried a single-process state machine? They are generally easier to design.

Comment: I used a single process now :

Comment: I edited my code and used a single process for it but still the count value is stuck in to zero and seems like it is not counting.

Comment: Well it's _almost_ a single process state machine.  But the sensitivity list is wrong, and it looks like you never actually change state! Hint : for a single process state machine, there should only be one signal for state...

Comment: Can some body please help me with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't synthetized it, but I think it should work. I you are not using VHDL2008, modify conditions so that bool types are returned:

```
ARCHITECTURE arc OF fsm_count IS

  type statetype is (s0,s1,s2);
  signal pr_state,nx_state: statetype;
  signal s_counter: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

begin

  process(clk) begin if rising_edge(clk) then
    if rst then pr_state <= s0; else pr_state <= nx_state; end if;
  end if; end process;

  process(clk) begin if rising_edge(clk) then
    if pr_state/=s1 then s_counter <= (others=>'0');
    else s_counter <= s_counter+1; end if;
  end if; end process;

  process(all) begin
    case pr_state is 

     when s0 => 
       if start then nx_state <= s1;
       else nx_state <= pr_state; end if;

     when s1 =>
       if s_counter?=12 then nx_state <= s2;
       else nx_state <= pr_state; end if;

     when s2 => 
       nx_state<= s0;

    end case;
  end process;

  don <= '1' when  (pr_state = s2) else '0';             

END arc;
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you can save `s2` (i replaced `pr_state` with `sta`, `nx_state` with `stn`, and `s_counter` with `cnt`:

```
ARCHITECTURE arc OF fsm_count IS

  signal idon: std_logic;
  type t_st is (s0,s1);
  signal sta, stn: t_st;
  signal cnt: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

begin

  process(clk) begin if rising_edge(clk) then
    if rst then sta <= s0; else sta <= stn; end if;
  end if; end process;

  process(clk) begin if rising_edge(clk) then
    if sta/=s1 then cnt <= (others=>'0');
    else cnt <= cnt+1; end if;
  end if; end process;

  process(all) begin
    case sta is 
     when s0 => 
       if start then stn <= s1; else stn<=sta; end if;
     when s1 =>
       if idon  then stn <= s0; else stn<=sta; end if;
    end case;
  end process;

  idon <= cnt?=12;             
  don <= idon;
END arc;
```

Or, you can just use a flag:

```
ARCHITECTURE arc OF fsm_count IS

  signal st, idon: std_logic;
  signal cnt: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

begin

  process(clk) begin if rising_edge(clk) then
    if sta/=s1 then cnt <= (others=>'0');
    else cnt <= cnt+1; end if;
  end if; end process;

  idon <= cnt?=12;             

  process(clk) begin if rising_edge(clk) then
    if rst then st <= '0';
    elsif not st and start then st <= '1';
    elsif st and idon then st <= '0'; end if;
  end if; end process;

  don <= idon;
END arc;
```